# Strange Recovery error when installing Windows 8

Tags: installation, drivers, windows-8

I have a four year old PC that I use as a HTPC.

It has been running Windows Vista 64bit. Now I want to install Windows 8 Pro 64bit from scratch (not an in-place-upgrade. I want to format the hard drive)

I have already installed Windows 8 from scratch on another Vista machine, and that went fine, so I am not a complete newbie.

It is a licensed RTM version of Windows 8, not a preview.

When I boot the HTPC from the installation DVD, I get the normal window graphic, but after a while I get this screen (this is the first time I have any chance to interact with the installation):

```
Recovery
Your PC needs to be repaired
The operating system couldn’t be loaded because a critical system driver is 
missing or contains errors.
File: \windows\system32\drivers\evbda.sys
Error code: 0xc0000098
You’ll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you 
don’t have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact 
your system administrator or PC manufacturer.

Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings.
```

I don’t understand what this means. I am trying to install a new operating system. 
Why is it claiming that my PC needs to be repaired? Do they mean the hardware? It was working before.

And what “operating system” is it talking about, the old Vista? Or is it saying that Windows 8 could not be loaded?

Why is it talking about recovery tools? I am installing a new operating system, there is nothing to recover.

It seems that evbda.sys is a driver for the ethernet hardware. But how would I replace it, again, this is during installation of a new operating system.

I have actually tried booting several times, and the exact file that it complains about varies!
It has also been \windows\system32\drivers\ACPI.sys and \windows\system32\config\system

If I press Enter it just re-displays the same screen.

If I press F8 I get the following screen

```
Startup Settings
Press a number to choose from the options below:
Use number keys or function keys F1-F9.
1) Enable debugging
2) Enable boot logging
3) Enable low-resolution video
4) Enable Safe Mode
5) Enable Safe Mode with Networking
6) Enable Safe Mode with Command Prompt
7) Disable driver signature enforcement
8) Disable early launch anti-malware protection
9) Disable automatic restart after failure
Press Enter to return to your operating system
```

I have tested pressing all buttons F1 to F9. None of them seem to have any effect whatsoever. They just return me to the earlier “Recovery” screen, I then press Enter, and the "Recovery" screen re-displays.

Again the alternatives are confusing: “Enable Safe Mode” - that sounds like it wants to boot into an existing environment, but I am trying to install a new operating system!

What can I do to make the installation proceed?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/itprovistasetup/thread/31089883-f6e6-4da6-9ba6-640275bbbf3b

Comment: Interesting link. It does indeed sound like a similar sort of problem, though with Vista (and not during installation). The way they solve it is to get to a command prompt and replace the driver. Unfortunately, in my case, there seems to be no way to get to a command prompt in the installer program. The "Enable Safe Mode with Command Prompt" option does not do anything.

Comment: On the off chance that there was something wrong with my installation media, I downloaded the same DVD form subscriber downloads again, and burned a new DVD. Using that, I got exactly the same problem.

Comment: Then probably something is wrong with your computer only.

Comment: But it ran Windows Vista ok for years.

Comment: Burn the iso to different brand of media

Comment: Burn it _slower_. And try using a different DVD drive in the old HTPC.

Comment: I tried a third DVD, it failed too. Then I tried installing from USB. That worked. So all the strange behaviours above were apparently due to DVD read problems.